# Add new column to pyspark dataframe without using UDF?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I currently have a pyspark dataframe and one of the columns contains rows of numbers that I would like to lookup using a function I wrote to return a string of information. I know the simple way would be to use withCoulmn and define a UDF to create a new column from the old one, however something about the way my function makes it unable to register it as a UDF.Is it possible for me to create a new dataframe with my new column based on the values of the old column without making a UDF?

Comment: did you try [inbuilt functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html)?

Comment: No built in function can do the lookup I require, to go from a number, make a request to an API and then return a string result

Comment: You need to find a way to combine the inbuilt functions. You will never get inbuilt functions satisfying your requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go from dataframe to rdd and then back to dataframe. For example, suppose you have a dataframe with two columns - 'col1' and 'col2':

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],['col1','col2'])
df.show()

+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   1|   2|
|   3|   4|
|   5|   6|
+----+----+
```

You could convert to an rdd, run it through a map, and return a tuple with 'col1', 'col2', and your new column - in this case 'col3' (gen_col_3 would be your function):

```
def gen_col_3(col1, col2):
    return col1 + col2

rdd = data.rdd.map(lambda x: (x['col1'], x['col2'], gen_col_3(x['col1'],x['col2'])))
```

Then you can convert back to a dataframe like so:

```
df = rdd.toDF(['col1','col2','col3'])
df.show()

+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|   3|
|   3|   4|   7|
|   5|   6|  11|
+----+----+----+
```